# "Error in file(con, "rb") : cannot open the connection" and not founding variables in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to make a variable in R with a txt archive, using the PNADcIBGE package.

My code is

```
dadosPNADc <- read_pnadc(microdata="C:/Users/info6/OneDrive/Área de Trabalho/R IC", 
                         input_txt="PNADC_012017.txt",
                         vars=raca_genero)
```

then it returns the error

> Variables V2010, V2007 not present in microdata.
>
> Error in file(con, "rb") : cannot open the connection

But the variable V2010 and v2007 do exists, and I don't know what about the file error

Comment: I think you need to escape the blank spaces. Like: `"C:/Users/info6/OneDrive/Área\ de\ Trabalho/R\ IC"`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered!

The function read_pnadc needs two inputs: microdata and input_txt, that are two archives
The microdata input needs a archive txt with the microdata from the PNADc. It needs the ".txt" at the end of the name of the archire
The input_txt input needs a archive with the dictionary of the variables used in the PNADc. You can get the archive in the documentation of the PNADcIBGE package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PNADcIBGE/PNADcIBGE.pdf)

My error was put the path of the working directory at the microdata input and put the microdata archive in the input_txt input